# Objective C: Is it possible not to show iOS Push Notifications in specific conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

Is it possible in iOS 7/8 not to show push notifications? In push `userInfo` I receive some data. Is it possible to check this data and show/not show this push notification? I need this when user have to logout from my application.

Comment: If a user logs out of your application, you should mark it as such on your server side. AppDelegate has a method `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, but that is only called when your application is running. If it's not, OS would have already shown the notification.

Comment: I've thought about it, thanks for advice

Comment: You can use the `content-available` key to send a 'silent' push notification and then issue a local notification if required.

Comment: @Paulw11 how to handle this key? And how to handle it in terminated app?

Comment: This key is described in the Apple Push notification guide - if your app is terminated then the notification will be displayed as normal.  If your app is in the background then the notification will be delivered to your app and not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, You can not stop notification from being shown in notification panel. When your app is in background/terminate state. First Notification is shown in notification panel.
  You can control show/hide notification in your application. When your app method didReceiveRemoteNotification is called.
  You can ask your back-end developer to send some flag whether this notification should be displayed or not.

Comment: If my back-end dev sends me some flag, how to handle it to show/not to show notification?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is possible in server side.when you get notification at the same time ask server side to send save that in one web service from that you have to get and show the details to user. 
 In app is open that time you able  get notification data  in didReceiveRemoteNotification.